# Dos click para cambiar de item (slider)

Tags: javascript, html5, typescript, ecmascript-6

estoy practicando un poco JavaScript y tratando de hacer las bases de un slider me encontré con un problema.

el problema es el siguiente:

Cuando le doy click a las flechas anterior o siguiente no se ejecuta la funcion a al primer click como sucede cuando lo seleccionas directamente, simplemente no hace nada y es hasta el segundo click que se ejecuta.

adjunto las funciones y el codigo en codepen al final.

```
function previousItem() {

// si el indice es igual a 0
if(index == 0) {
    index = botones.length; //el indice es igual es igual a length de los botones
}

// El indice disminuye en cada click
index -= 1;

// Establece el indice activo donde el inicial es el 0
activeIndex = botones[index];


for (let i = 0; i < botones.length; i++) {
    const BOTON:any = botones[i];

    //si el Boton es igual el indice activo agrega estilo
    if(BOTON == activeIndex) {
        BOTON.style.color = "orange";
    } else {
        BOTON.style.color = "#4c4c4c"; // Si no lo resetea
    }

}
```

};

```
function nextItem() {

// si el indice es igual la length de botones
if(index == botones.length) {
    index = 0; //el indice es igual a 0
}

// Establece el indice activo donde el inicial es el 0
activeIndex = botones[index];


for (let i = 0; i < botones.length; i++) {
    const BOTON:any = botones[i];

    //si el Boton es igual el indice activo agrega el estilo
    if(BOTON == activeIndex) {
        BOTON.style.color = "orange";
    } else {
        BOTON.style.color = "#4c4c4c"; // Si no lo resetea
    }

}

// El indice aumenta en cada click
index += 1;
```

};

Aca adjunto todo lo que trato de realizar por codepen.

See the Pen [Active without classes](https://codepen.io/Flixwick/pen/GYeWoR/) by Flixwick ([@Flixwick](https://codepen.io/Flixwick)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Gracias a los que respondan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en `nextItem()`. Lo que estabas haciendo era incrementar el index justo al final, cuando debería ser lo primero en realizar. Llevándolo al comienzo de la función se soluciona. Quedaría así:

```js
// Seleccion de los botones
var botones = document.querySelectorAll('button');
//Variable Indice
var index = 0;
// Indice Activo
var activeIndex;
var _loop_1 = function (i) {
    botones[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var esto = this;
        for (i = 0; i < botones.length; i++) {
            if (esto !== botones[i]) {
                botones[i].style.color = "#4c4c4c";
            }
            else {
                esto.style.color = "orange";
                index = i;
                console.log(index);
            }
        }
    });
    out_i_1 = i;
};
var out_i_1;
//
// ─── ACTIVE ITEM ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
//
for (var i = 0; i < botones.length; i++) {
    _loop_1(i);
    i = out_i_1;
}
//
// ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── FIN  ACTIVE ─────
//
//
// ─── ACTIVE CON FLECHAS ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
//
//Event Listeners
var flechaIzq = document.getElementById('flecha_i');
var flechaDer = document.getElementById('flecha_d');
flechaIzq.addEventListener('click', previousItem);
flechaDer.addEventListener('click', nextItem);
// ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
//Funciones
//
// ─── ITEM ANTERIOR ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
//
function previousItem() {
    // si el indice es igual a 0
    if (index == 0) {
        index = botones.length; //el indice es igual es igual a length de los botones
    }
    // El indice disminuye en cada click
    index -= 1;
    // Establece el indice activo donde el inicial es el 0
    activeIndex = botones[index];
    for (var i = 0; i < botones.length; i++) {
        var BOTON = botones[i];
        //si el Boton es igual el indice activo agrega estilo
        if (BOTON == activeIndex) {
            BOTON.style.color = "orange";
        }
        else {
            BOTON.style.color = "#4c4c4c"; // Si no lo resetea
        }
    }
}
;
//
// ─── ITEM SIGUIENTE ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
//
function nextItem() {
    // El indice aumenta en cada click
    index += 1;
    // si el indice es igual la length de botones
    if (index == botones.length) {
        index = 0; //el indice es igual a 0
    }
    // Establece el indice activo donde el inicial es el 0
    activeIndex = botones[index];
    for (var i = 0; i < botones.length; i++) {
        var BOTON = botones[i];
        //si el Boton es igual el indice activo agrega el estilo
        if (BOTON == activeIndex) {
            BOTON.style.color = "orange";
        }
        else {
            BOTON.style.color = "#4c4c4c"; // Si no lo resetea
        }
    }
    
}
;
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
button{
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  margin: 1rem .5rem;
  background: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  
  }
i{
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
.contenedor{
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>



    <div class="contenedor">
        <i id="flecha_i"> < </i>

        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
        <button>4</button>
        <button>5</button>

        <i id="flecha_d">></i>
    </div>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Saludos!**